# delete empty rows of a google sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets

this is my google sheet doc https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_cEg21VCXg8DfmCO45_314iwszmmqiC6GGh3eFxUcWs/edit?usp=sharing
i need to detele the empty rows, i save  all data in this way in python.

```py
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("pythonsheetsprue0.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

spreadsheet = client.open("Libro Diario").worksheet("Libro")
lista = spreadsheet.get_all_values()
```

i try this but it does no`for i in range(len(lista)): if lista[i-1][3] == " ": lista.remove(lista[i-1])`

Comment: I am unable to test this myself without the credentials JSON but besides that, within the for loop, print out the values for `lista[i-1][3]` to see if any of them actually equal `" "`

Comment: When I saw "Libro" sheet in your provided sample Spreadsheet, I cannot understand your expected situation. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing for a space with `' '` on purpose? if the row is truly empty the test should be`''`.

Although in this particular spreadsheet you may be able to rely on the 3rd cell being empty to discard an entire row, here's one way to check the entire row before discarding it, makes it a little more robust.

```
lista = wks.get_all_values()
nrows = len(lista) + 1
i=0
while i < nrows-1:
    try:
        next(s for s in lista[i] if s)
        i = i + 1
    except StopIteration: 
        lista.remove(lista[i])      
        # to edit the spreadsheet itself, use delete_row()
        wks.delete_row(i+1)
        nrows -= 1
```